# How to Call Jquery tabdrop() Plugin from Jquery Tab Widget?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

Just as this [Jquery Plugin](https://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-tabdrop/), I have jquery tab that I would like it to behave the way that plugin does by grouping any exceeded tab into dropdown as it reaches the screen width.

[image: example of jquery tabdrop]

In my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gstnhk18/2/) sample code , I tried call this plugin but still my tab does not move into drop down group.

```
$(function() {
  var tabTitle = $("#tab_title"),
    tabContent = $("#tab_content"),
    tabTemplate = "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close' role='presentation'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
    tabCounter = 2;

  var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
  // Modal dialog init: custom buttons and a "close" callback resetting the form inside
  var dialog = $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      Add: function() {
        addTab();
        $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    },
    close: function() {
      form[0].reset();
    }
  });

  // AddTab form: calls addTab function on submit and closes the dialog
  var form = dialog.find("form").on("submit", function(event) {
    addTab();
    dialog.dialog("close");
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  // Actual addTab function: adds new tab using the input from the form above
  function addTab() {
    var label = tabTitle.val() || "Tab " + tabCounter,
      id = "tabs-" + tabCounter,
      li = $(tabTemplate.replace(/#\{href\}/g, "#" + id).replace(/#\{label\}/g, label)),
      tabContentHtml = tabContent.val() || "Tab " + tabCounter + " content.";

    tabs.find(".ui-tabs-nav").append(li);
    tabs.append("<div id='" + id + "'><p>" + tabContentHtml + "</p></div>");
    tabs.tabs("refresh");
    tabCounter++;
  }

  // AddTab button: just opens the dialog
  $("#add_tab")
    .button()
    .on("click", function() {
      dialog.dialog("open");
    });

  // Close icon: removing the tab on click
  tabs.on("click", "span.ui-icon-close", function() {
    var panelId = $(this).closest("li").remove().attr("aria-controls");
    $("#" + panelId).remove();
    tabs.tabs("refresh");
  });


  $('#tabs').tabdrop(); // Here Where I Called Plugin TabDrop
});
```

I could not use this plugin directly because my current project is using Jquery tab instead and I don't want my tab fall down into new line as user open many tabs.

Therefore, how can I achieve that result for current project? Thanks

Comment: You mean that when you have the multiple tabs, the dropdown tab doesn't appear, right?

Comment: @Tomato32, exactly, when the multiple tabs expand exceed the width of screen, it should group together the newly created tabs as what bootstrap-tabdrop does, however it does not work. I would like to use bootstrap-tabdrop plugin for this case. Thanks

Comment: Is it okey to use my own jq instead of bootstrap or dose it have to be bootstrap only

Comment: @Alen.Toma, it would be great, just my purpose is to reduce the tabs as that plugin does because when my application when viewing on small device screen, the view is blocked  easily by the tabs when it is long, therefore I wish it to works similar as that tabdrop plugin, but it's quite fine when viewing on desktop. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i have created my own `tabdrop` that will work on mobile and also check for screen size.

Have a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/raj13syh/) and let me know what you think

Make sure to look at function `tabdrop`, the css and design of the dropdown you can modify as you like as i did not really had much time with.

The dropdown will appear when there is to many tabs that exeed the window size.

Comment: just a brief look, it works very nice, the functionality, Please let me test a little more as I will include in my real project. I will let you know feedback soonest. Thank very much :)

Comment: after tested I found some issues. 1st, dropdrop does not trigger dropdown as soon as tabs increase and reach the screen with until we resize the screen. 2nd, dropdown does not appear on the first exceeded tab until there are 2 or 3 exceeded tabs. 3rd if active tab is on the last tab or any tab not first tab, the active was move into dropdown leaving me don't know which tab I am currently on, can we make that active tab title appear as dropdown icon if the active tab is in drop down? just as tabdrop plugin does? Thanks

Comment: 1 Issue, hade some fixes and also you have to trigger `tabdrop()` on `addtabs` like the example above. 2 issue, is fixed, 3 issue, now the active tab will always be the last visiable tab, so you will able to tell which tab is active. Make sure to trigger `tabdrop` on addtab so the dropdown will appear if needed. Let me know if there is other issues. the link is updated now

Comment: Sorry for late feedback. and thanks very much for your help, it's working fine; however I need to do some customization for my real project such css style, and how it group into dropdown. However, I got some this basic from you, it's really help. Thanks so much :)